# wordpress autoload options enable on specific pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My wordpress database table ***wp_options*** have 2200 rows which set as autoload is **Yes**.
I am going to disable all autoload to **No** But as i cant do all so i want to do for specific option rows.

I tried to find the options which are necessary to run wordpress and woocommerce only but unable to find on internet.

Please can you help me on following

1- is option those are set to autoload = Yes , loads on every page or it loads only on their specific plugin pages where plugin loads?

2- What should be the necessary autoload option to run wordpress only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found one good plugin for this which allows user to disable specific plugin load on specific pages.

https://celtislab.net/en/wp-plugin-load-filter-addon/